# Add a character to each item in a list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of suits of cards as follows:

`suits = ["h","c", "d", "s"]`

and I want to add a type of card to each suit, so that my result is something like

`aces = ["ah","ac", "ad", "as"]`

is there an easy way to do this without recreating an entirely new list and using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This would have to be the 'easiest' way

```
>>> suits = ["h","c", "d", "s"]
>>> aces = ["a" + suit for suit in suits]
>>> aces
['ah', 'ac', 'ad', 'as']
```

Comment: also, `list('a' + suit for suit in suits)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Unless for some reason you need a `tuple` eg. `tuple('a' + suit for suit in suits)`. I would definitely not use that for lists.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid what's wrong with the list comprehension is the question

Comment: @jamylak Works for beginning, but not end.  so, e.g., `aces = [suit for suit in suits + "a"]` does not work.  Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: @jamylak My dumbness.  This works: `aces = [suit + "a" for suit in suits] `

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative, the map function:

```
aces = map(( lambda x: 'a' + x), suits)
```

Comment: List comp is *usually* preferred when you need to have `lambda`s  in your map, in which case they are also faster

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add something different than always 'a' you can try this too:

```
foo = ['h','c', 'd', 's']
bar = ['a','b','c','d']
baz = [x+y for x, y in zip(foo, bar)]
>>> ['ha', 'cb', 'dc', 'sd']
```

Comment: `''.join([x, y])` == `x + y`