# How to append character to specific part of item in list - Python

Tags: python, list, append, character

I have the following list `Novar`:

`["'population_3000|road_class_3_3000'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000|trafBuf25'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000|trafBuf25|population_1000'"]`

How can I append a character (e.g. `$`) to *a specific part of* the items in the list, for instance to `road_class_3_3000`, so that the upgraded list becomes:

`["'population_3000|road_class_3_3000$'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000$|trafBuf25'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000$|trafBuf25|population_1000'"]`

Most similar questions on Stack Overflow seem to focus on manipulating the item itself, rather than *a part* of the item, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63192224/how-to-rename-selected-items-in-a-list-while-ignoring-others) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738267/add-a-character-to-each-item-in-a-list).

Therefore, applying the following code:

```
    if (item == "road_class_3_3000"):
        item.append("$")
```

Would be of no use since `road_class_3_3000` is part of the items `"'population_3000|road_class_3_3000'"`, `"'population_3000|road_class_3_3000|trafBuf25'"` and  `"'population_3000|road_class_3_3000|trafBuf25|population_1000'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might harness [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module (part of standard library) for this task following way

```
import re
novar = ["'population_3000|road_class_3_3000'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000|trafBuf25'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000|trafBuf25|population_1000'"]
novar2 = [re.sub(r'(?<=road_class_3_3000)', '$', i) for i in novar]
print(novar2)
```

output

```
["'population_3000|road_class_3_3000$'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000$|trafBuf25'", "'population_3000|road_class_3_3000$|trafBuf25|population_1000'"]
```

Feature I used is called *positive lookbehind*, it is kind of zero-length assertion. I look for place after `road_class_3_3000` of zer-length, which I then replace using `$` character.

Comment: How would this apply if there is an additional part to the item that contains ```road_class_3_30000``` whereby you do not want the operation to affect that part? Applying ```[re.sub(r'(?<=road_class_3_3000)', '$', i) for i in novar]``` would, in this case, also result in ```road_class_3_3000$0``` (while you want ```road_class_3_30000``` intact).

Comment: @FoekeBoersma to prevent such behavior replace `r'(?<=road_class_3_3000)'` using `r'(?<=road_class_3_3000)\b'` where `\b` is another zero-length assertion which is word boundary, see [`re` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for further discussion of that feature